# skip nodes having attributes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

This is my sample xml. I want to remove the node  **`<shared-variation-attribute/>`**
 in first variation node. but want to keep in the second variation node along with **Removing the regular empty nodes as**

```
 <variation-attribute>
 <variation-attribute-values/>
 </variation-attribute>
```

Means how to skip nodes having attributes

```
<ItemList>
       <Variation>
          <attributes>
             <shared-variation-attribute/>
             <variation-attribute attribute-id="Colour" att-id="Colour">
                <display-name>Colour</display-name>
                <variation-attribute-values>
                   <variation-attribute-value value="Bronze">
                      <display-value>Bronze</display-value>
                   </variation-attribute-value>
                   <variation-attribute-value value="BRZE UNI EMBELLISSEU">
                      <display-value>BRZE UNI EMBELLISSEU</display-value>
                   </variation-attribute-value>
                </variation-attribute-values>
             </variation-attribute>
          </attributes>
          <Variants>
             <variant product-id="124451575"/>
          </Variants>
       </Variation>
       <Variation>
          <attributes>
             <shared-variation-attribute variation-attribute-id="Colour" attribute-id="Colour"/>
             <variation-attribute>
                <variation-attribute-values/>
             </variation-attribute>
          </attributes>
          <Variants>
             <variant product-id="180003356"/>
             <variant product-id="180003372"/>
             <variant product-id="180003364"/>
             <variant product-id="180003380"/>
             <variant product-id="180003398"/>
          </Variants>
       </Variation>
    </ItemList>
```

I tried code like this:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*/*[not(node())]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it is removing all the self closing tags. But I want to keep the node like `<variant product-id="180003372"/>`. How to achieve this using XSLT

Expected output is like :

```
    <ItemList>
   <Variation>
      <attributes>
         <variation-attribute attribute-id="Colour" att-id="Colour">
            <display-name>Colour</display-name>
            <variation-attribute-values>
               <variation-attribute-value value="Bronze">
                  <display-value>Bronze</display-value>
               </variation-attribute-value>
               <variation-attribute-value value="BRZE UNI EMBELLISSEU">
                  <display-value>BRZE UNI EMBELLISSEU</display-value>
               </variation-attribute-value>
            </variation-attribute-values>
         </variation-attribute>
      </attributes>
      <Variants>
         <variant product-id="124451575"/>
      </Variants>
   </Variation>
   <Variation>
      <attributes>
         <shared-variation-attribute variation-attribute-id="Colour" attribute-id="Colour"/>
      </attributes>
      <Variants>
         <variant product-id="180003356"/>
         <variant product-id="180003372"/>
         <variant product-id="180003364"/>
         <variant product-id="180003380"/>
         <variant product-id="180003398"/>
      </Variants>
   </Variation>
</ItemList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes are not matched by a `node()` so you need to change your template to this instead....

```
<xsl:template match="*/*[not(node()) and not(@*)]"/>
```

EDIT: If you want to remove parent nodes if all of its descendant nodes are "empty", then try this expression instead

```
<xsl:template match="*/*[not(descendant-or-self::*[@* or text()])]"/>
```

Comment: I tried your code. But there is still one empty node present like  <variation-attribute/> in second variation

Comment: This empty node <variation-attribute/> still remain in output xml because this hierarchy <variation-attribute>
                   <variation-attribute-values/>
                     </variation-attribute>     what to do in this case?

Comment: So, are you saying you want to remove the parent element, if all it's child nodes are empty? It would probably help if you edit your question to show your expected output. Thank you!

Comment: Hey Tim, I have added expected output.. can you please suggest what can we do in this case?

Comment: I've amended my answer with another solution to try.

Comment: Its Working.. Thank you so much for your help..!!

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted, so that other people coming here don't have to read through all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This would select all Variation nodes, which have at least one attribute.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("TestFile.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> elementList = doc.XPathSelectElements("ItemList/Variation[attributes/shared-variation-attribute[(@*)]]");
```

Similarly you can use

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("TestFile.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> elementList = doc.XPathSelectElements("ItemList/Variation[attributes/shared-variation-attribute[not(@*)]]");
```

to select nodes which do not have any attribute.

Comment: The question has been modified. :(

Comment: Sorry. Changing questions after they have been answered is evil.